# What is the PayPal IPN reply url?

Tags: paypal-ipn

In its guide, PayPal specifies the following:

1. The API operation initiates a payment on PayPal.
2. PayPal sends your IPN listener a message that notifies you of the event
3. ***Your listener sends the complete unaltered message back to PayPal***; the message must contain the same fields in the same order and be encoded in the same way as the original message
4. PayPal sends a single word back, which is either VERIFIED if the message originated with PayPal or INVALID if there is any discrepancy with what was originally sent

What is the URL where we need to send the reply specified by step 3? Is this something we need to obtain from the HTTP request?

Guide: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs are shown in the examples. There's one for the sandbox, and one for the real service. Append the received parameters to the end of the url to complete it.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&...

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate&...

Comment: And the decision as to which to use is based on whether test_ipn=1 in the received parameters.